# pandas get the value and the location from another DataFrame and make a series

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say, I have a DataFrame (dfrtn)

```
    A    B    C    D    E    F
0  33   34   35   36   37   38
1  39   40   41   42   43   44
2  45   46   47   48   49   50
3  51   52   53   54   55   56
4  57   58   59   60   61   62
```

then, I make another DataFrame (dfrtn2) from dfrtn (dfrtn2 = dfrtn % 7)

```
    A    B    C    D    E    F
0   5    6    0    1    2    3
1   4    5    6    0    1    2
2   3    4    5    6    0    1
3   2    3    4    5    6    0
4   1    2    3    4    5    6
```

I want to add two new columns, "Minimum" and "MinCol" like this

```
    Minimum   MinCol
0   0         C
1   0         D
2   0         E
3   0         F
4   1         A
```

I just have the source dataframe only, can't make the Minimum and Miminum Column

```
dfrtn = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(33,63).reshape(5,6), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F'])
dfrtn2 = rtn % 7
```

I tried to use this, but can't solve yet.

```
for x in dfrtn.T.idxmin()
```

anyone can help me, please?

===============================

Thanks, I really appreciate it and here's an Additional Question...
If I want to get the value from dfrtn which is the same location of dfrtn2, how can I do this?

result should be

```
    Minimum   MinCol
0   35        C
1   42        D
2   49        E
3   56        F
4   57        A
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `dfrtn2.min()` will give you a series where the index is the column name and the value is the minimum value from that column. Is that what you want? E: ok that's not it, but try looking into `dfrtn2.min(axis=1)` and `np.argmin` function

Comment: @RobinNemeth thanks, I added one more question. please see the Question again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `DataFrame` contructor with [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.idxmin.html) and `min` per rows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'MinCol': dfrtn2.idxmin(axis=1), 
                   'Minimum': dfrtn2.min(axis=1)}, columns=['Minimum','MinCol'])
print (df1)
   Minimum MinCol
0        0      C
1        0      D
2        0      E
3        0      F
4        1      A
```

For original values add [`lookup`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.lookup.html)

```
df1['new'] = dfrtn.lookup(dfrtn.index, df1['MinCol'])
print (df1)
   Minimum MinCol  new
0        0      C   35
1        0      D   42
2        0      E   49
3        0      F   56
4        1      A   57
```

---

```
df1['Minimum'] = dfrtn.lookup(dfrtn.index, df1['MinCol'])
print (df1)
   Minimum MinCol
0       35      C
1       42      D
2       49      E
3       56      F
4       57      A
```

Comment: Thanks jezrael, I just added one more question, could you help me with this again?

Comment: @B.A. - Sure, what is question?

Comment: @B.A. - Do you need new column to new `DataFrame` ?